# What's the difference between kernel and stepwise logistic regression?

Tags: regression, machine-learning

I am confused by different terms of logistic regression. What are the differences between stepwise, kernel, forward, and backward?

Comment: one of these doesn't belong. the others could be googled: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stepwise_regression. Might want to expand questions to focus on specific question.

Answer (score 4):

Kernel logistic regression (KLR) refers to using logistic regression into a kernel induced feature space, as is more common in [support vector machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine) (SVM). By working in a feature space, kernel methods (including KLR) can be used to model nonlinear relationships. KLR is less popular than SVM because it's much slower to train models and typically does not offer better predictive performance.

Stepwise (logistic) regression refers to an implicit feature selection mechanism baked into the regression modeling process. Stepwise procedures are a controversial issue: the feature selection works well in some situations but with statistical issues that need to be addressed (poor estimates of model uncertainty). Because of this, stepwise regression is sometimes used as an example of data dredging.

Forward, backward and bidirectional elimination or different approaches used in stepwise regression.

Comment: Hmmm... "they tend to work well..." is ambiguous. In simple situations w/ large clear effects they tend to select the correct features (outside of that, not necessarily). OTOH, estimates are biased, CI's too narrow, p-values meaningless, etc, so they don't work well for those issues. Nonetheless +1

Comment: @gung you are right, I rephrased it to be a little more conservative. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Thanks! So, why will kernel logistic regression appear if it does not work better than the stepwise logistic regression? Is there any advantages of using kernel one?

Comment: @RockTheStar KLR is nonlinear modeling whereas stepwise LR is LR with baked-in feature selection. These two cannot be compared directly. KLR *does* offer better generalization performance than LR when the task at hand is nonlinear (assuming an appropriate kernel is being used).

Answer (score 3):

All you need to know about stepwise is that it's ambiguous, inefficient, and a bad approach to feature selection. You begin by defining a selection criterion (oft neglected in the discussion of stepwise), but we can safely assume that AIC is the best choice. AIC is a likelihood / complexity tradeoff that is used to evaluate competing models of vastly different applications (when standard likelihood testing would not be appropriate). Stepwise regression successively adds (forward) or subtracts (backward) model terms iteratively (huge risk for local minima compared to best subsets regression) until an apparently optimal AIC is obtained, and that is called the target model.

As a note, none of these terms are specific to logistic regression. It's just that logistic regression is especially well-suited to estimating a binary classifier and its associated uncertainty.

Comment: In statistics, the term kernel is typically used in the context of density estimation. In machine learning, as is the case for kernel logistic regression, kernels are functions that define an inner product in *some* feature space. As far as I know, there is no direct relationship between the two uses of the word kernel, which can be quite confusing (especially when talking about Gaussian kernels).

Comment: @MarcClaesen That's interesting, and confusing I agree. I'll provide edits.

Comment: Sometimes stepwise (wide sense) means any selection based on comparing model fits with differing predictors, including forward only (you can only add predictors), backward only (you can only remove predictors), and both. Sometimes it means (narrow sense) only a method based on forward and backward steps combined, or both at least possible. I've done no literature survey, but my impression is that the wider sense is dominant.